# How to render a PDF in the browser that is retrieve via rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, recurly

I have a rails app that uses [Recurly](https://docs.recurly.com/). I am attempting to download a PDF and render it in the browser. I currently have a link:

```
link_to 'Download', get_invoice_path(:number => invoice.invoice_number)
```

The associated controller has the `get_invoice` method that looks like so:

```
def get_invoice
    begin
      @pdf = Recurly::Invoice.find(params[:number], :format => 'pdf')
    rescue Recurly::Resource::NotFound => e
      flash[:error] = 'Invoice not found.'
    end
  end
```

When I click the link I get the PDF rendered in my console in binary form. How do I make this render the PDF in the browser?

Comment: Maybe try this: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_file

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming the PDF is saved in memory, use the [`send_data`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_data) to send the data stream back in the browser.

```
def get_invoice
  @pdf = Recurly::Invoice.find(params[:number], :format => 'pdf')
  send_data @pdf, filename: "#{params[:number]}.pdf", type: :pdf
end
```

If the file is stored somewhere (but this doesn't seem to be your case), use [`send_file`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_file).

Comment: this works, but still causes the pdf to be rendered in binary form in the console. Any way to avoid this?

Comment: Zack, this depends on the logger settings of your environment. In development, it's likely the logger is set to `info` or `debug`, therefore a bunch of stuff will be sent to the console. The only way to avoid this is changing the settings. To be honest, I would not worry too much.

Answer (score 18):

You don't render the PDF to the browser, you send it as a file.  Like so:

```
# GET /something/:id[.type]
def show
  # .. set @pdf variable
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { # html page }
    format.pdf do
      send_file(@pdf, filename: 'my-awesome-pdf.pdf', type: 'application/pdf')
    end
  end
end
```

The HTML response isn't needed if you aren't supporting multiple formats.

If you want to show the PDF in the browser instead of starting a download, add `disposition: :inline` to the `send_file` call.

Comment: disposition: :inline was exactly what I was looking for ! It renders in the browser instead of downloading