# rails pdf suddenly render encrypted text instead of function to download pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf

I have an app that have the function to download pdf. It was working all fine, but after several commit my pdf function just render encrypted text. 
the function that trigger the pdf link[image]

```
  def print_pdf
    airwaybill = Airwaybill.find(params[:airwaybill_id])
    pdf = InvoicePdf.new(airwaybill, current_user)
    puts "#{}"
    send_data pdf.render, filename: "Airwaybill(#{airwaybill.airwaybill_no}).pdf" , type: 'application.pdf'
  end
```

what could be the most common problem for this issue?

Comment: Did you try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26768608/how-to-render-a-pdf-in-the-browser-that-is-retrieve-via-rails-controller?

Comment: tried already, but still got the binary